# Updating column based on the multiple conditions ref another workbook

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I am stuck at this the array formula for which I would like multiple conditions.

Here is the main workbook [MO Listing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WwWqZMexma0Sf_6s4yoOPyC2dzFl6mRWNsjPbqAccvs/edit#gid=0)

to update the 'Status' column referring to this workbook

Comment: what is your formula? where? what conditions? edit your question

Comment: Hi there,I trying to use the arrayformula at 'Status' column in [MO Listing] to determine the value by ref it  using vlookup by MO NO.

The formula is in MO Listing Sheet1! A1.

Condition A : In table PRC Records table , PRC!C:C is not blank = "On Hold"
Condition B: In table PRC Records table, PRC Detail! C:C is not blank " On "Production "
Condition C: In MO listing table ,'Balance Qty' =< 0  will be "Completed"Thanks. Player0

Comment: I take it that 99% of those "DRAFT" statuses should be "On Production" ?

Comment: or they should be empty?

Comment: Only row 93 should be On Production whereby the rest should be 'Draft".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={"Status"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B), ,
 IF((MINUS(I2:I,J2:J)) < (0.1*I2:I), "Completed", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B$2:B, 
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0", "PRC!A$2:C"),
 "where Col3 is not null", 0), 3, 0), IF(ISBLANK(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B$2:B, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0", "PRC Detail!B$2:C"), 2, 0))),
 "DRAFT", "On Production")))))}
```

[image]